# Function to extract requencies of numbers in rows in R

Tags: r, function, frequency

I need a function, which checks for the frequency of values per row in a df, then checks whether one of the values appears 6 or more times, and if so, displays this value in a new column. If not, writes "nope" in the same new column instead.
In the example below: The values in the rows are either 1, 2, or 3. So if one of the values 1,2,or3 appears 6 or more times per row, whichever value that is (1,2,or3) has to appear in a new column. If none of the values appear 6 or more times per row, the value in that same new column should be "nope".
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGKmC.png)

Comment: You can check for `apply` and `table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try applying the `table` function for each row using

```
make_count_col <- function(x) {
  cnt <- apply(x, 1, table)
  x$newcolumn <- apply(cnt, 2, function(y) {
    if (max(y, na.rm = T) < 6)
      out <- 'nope'
    else
      out <- names(y)[which.max(y)]
    out
    })
  x
}
```

Your example replicated

```
x <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3,
                            2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3), nrow = 2, byrow = T))
colnames(x) <- paste0('svo', 1:9)
make_count_col(x)
  svo1 svo2 svo3 svo4 svo5 svo6 svo7 svo8 svo9 newcolumn
     1    2    1    2    2    2    2    2    3         2
     2    3    1    1    3    2    1    1    3      nope
```

Comment: Dear Ben, thanks, but I get the "Dim(x) must have a positive length" error, which basically tells me that it cannot apply :) the apply function to object cnt, since the object cnt is a list. I tried creating the cnt object outside the function with "apply(x, 1, table)", but when I attach it back to the dataframe, it creates a column with vectors, containing the number if occurances, This naturally downgrades the whole dataframe into a list and I cannot further apply the max function.

Comment: Can you provide a better example of what you are passing to the function as `x`? I tried using what you gave above and it works for me.

Comment: Dear Ben, thanks, It was a stuck R session :( Thank you very much for your help

Comment: btw, do you have some knowledge of binomial regressions? I posted a question here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229477/interactions-in-binomial-logistic-regression, but it is a bit complex...